# Parasitic capacitance in PCB high speed traces

Tags: pcb, capacitance, parasitic-capacitance

I am learning high speed pcb designing and the parasitic capacitance is making few things difficult to comprehend. I understand how because of parasitic inductance cross talk emi and signal integrity issues are happening in pcb but I don't understand how the parasitic capacitance whose effects are prominent at high frequencies is storing charge between traces because capacitor store charge so parasitic capacitance is the capacitance between two high speed traces separated by the dielectric, so how it store charge and how cross talk emi and signal integrity issues are happening because of parasitic capacitance.

Comment: Do you understand that at high frequencies capacitors become short circuits?

Comment: What do you mean "*How does it store charge?*" What kind of answer are you expecting? Because it's not any different than how a purpose built capacitor stores charge.

Comment: Hmm I had always assumed crosstalk was a largely capacitive phenomenon, I must mull the inductive coupling as well.

Comment: @user1850479 yeah because dielectric 
polarization just can't keep up with the fast switching of signal but still current doesn't leak out from one side and reach to the other side (unless dielectric breakdown happens) so how current appears in another trace due to first trace.

Comment: @DKNguyen well actually I am thinking parasitic capacitance in transmission lines works as a normal capacitor (I am taking literal meaning ) but the think that has confused me a lot is that normal capacitor stores charge in the form of electrical field lines but in transmission lines we have magnetic field lines because of changing signals so when these magnetic field lines link to the other trace they induce current but this is an inductor phenomena so as the name suggest parasitic capacitance it should store charge right so how it is storing charge and if not then why that so so

Comment: In a transmission line you have the capacitance for the electric fields and the inductance for the magnetic fields. The inductance affects the change in currents and the capacitor affects the change in voltage.

Comment: @Bryan yeah I guess so because capacitive action show these behaviors as well but at high frequencies but it's a capacitive phenomena so there should be an intuition behind how so

Comment: @DKNguyen this is I am not understanding because no stored charge is present there even if the rise time is very fast signal is changing so there should be only inductive phenomena because of magnetic field lines

Comment: Why are you saying no charge is stored? Why are you saying there should only be inductive phenomena? You also need to make a distinction between a rise time in voltage or current.

Comment: @DKNguyen "the capacitor affects the change in voltage" can you elaborate this part and can you explicitly explain how charge is storing would be a major help

Comment: I'm not even sure what there is to explain really. Whenever current flows through a capacitor in one direction charge is stored in it. It's as simple as that. The more charge is stored, the more the capacitor opposes the voltage that is trying to push current through it. Just like any other capacitor. If you assume an infinite or very large capacitor, it takes longer for this to happen so if your current is constantly reversing direction (like noise or non-DC currents) the capacitor's opposition doesn't really affect things too much since it's always mostly empty.

Comment: A consequence of this is that the voltage across a capacitor takes time to change and therefore capacitors limit how quickly the voltage can change since you need time to pump enough charge into the capacitor to bring the voltage difference between its two ends to a certain voltage. An inductor does something similar with current.

Comment: @DKNguyen I am confused there because in the normal capacitor we have plates to store charge so when current flows through the capacitor because of dielectric polarization stored charged in capacitor remains stored(stays on the plate and don't go anywhere from one plate and due to electric field repulsion electrons from the other plate causes current) when the plates are completely charged the capacitor is fully charged so like that here if we assume the traces as plate then the charge is not storing they act like a short circuit at high freq. So there is no E fields among traces only M fields

Comment: @Bryan I believe you see crosstalk via the magnetic field mostly in high powered devices like motors where operating currents are much larger.

Comment: @DKNguyen see that I knew, and I would call that "interference"; "crosstalk" to me is between communication lines specifically.

Comment: @Bryan Yeah. *Interference* is the word I couldn't come up with. I tend to think of cross talk as between signals only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem. The problem is you're not sure what assumptions are being made and what is important for the issue at hand so you're trying to account for everything.

1. A given capacitance presents a lower and lower impedance as the
   frequency applied to it increases.
2. If the capacitance is large enough and the frequency is high enough
   the impedance presented approaches that of a short-circuit. But
   there are no true short-circuits. Everything has an impedance and
   parasitic capacitance and inductance.
3. When talking about cross talk and parasitic capacitances, the
   following assumption is made: We only care about crosstalk when there is enough power in it and parasitic capacitances are parasitic
   so tend to be very small. With such a small parasitic capacitance, this means that only sufficiently high frequencies are presented with a low enough impedance by the capacitor to efficiently flow into other parts of the circuit (aka crosstalk). So when talking about crosstalk we are assuming that the capacitances involved are large enough to present a low impedance to the frequencies involved. Or, conversely, we assume that the frequencies are high enough relative to the capacitor involved to see a low impedance.
   charge to flow for us to care about the leakage.
4. For non-DC frequencies, there is no such thing as "completely charged". There is no final voltage level for the capacitor to reach since it's non-DC. The signal is always changing so the capacitor voltage is always trying to catch up.

   One extreme case of this is applying an "infinite DC voltage" to the capacitor. Even though it's DC, unlike a finite DC voltage, the capacitor can never catch up and so is always charging. The capacitor in this case is effectively low impedance. We obviously can't do this in real life but you can approximate it in a different sense by constantly making the capacitor play catch-up quickly enough with a high frequency so it can never "rest" on any one voltage for very long because if it can that means it is able to more effectively present an opposing voltage close to the applied voltage to resist current flowing through it which what an impedance does.
5. If your capacitance is small enough and your frequency is low enough
   such that the capacitor is able to charge to the peak value of the
   signal and remain like that for "enough time", that's basically
   saying your capacitor is not a short-circuit because it's impedance
   at that frequency is high enough to effectively oppose the current
   flow being produced by the applied voltage.

**EDIT:**
You're not thinking that while the capacitor is charging up and storing charge it is stopping the signal do you? It's not like how if the post office is storing incoming letters, then there are no outgoing letters and therefore there is no messages passing through the post office. –

Are you perhaps missing that if a capacitor is charging up, current must be flowing through it and therefore a signal is passing through the capcaitor? (such as when non-DC is applied to the the capacitor) Whereas if a capacitor is not charging up then there must be no current flowing through it which means there is no signal passing through the capacitor (such as when a capacitor has finished charging up to a constant DC voltage applied to it).

Comment: The points are really helpful for parasitic capacitance in IC designing as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate this "So when talking about crosstalk we are assuming that the capacitances involved" that's the problem I just couldn't comprehend  how two different signal traces routed close to each other carrying high frequency signals having voltage difference between them will have capacitance between them can have cross talk due to capacitance. The cross talk should be due to inductor phenomena how charge storing ability (capacitance) between them is causing cross talk.

Comment: @Ahsan I don't know why you keep saying that the cross talk should be due to inductor phenomena. Suppose I have two conductors and I connect them together with a capacitor and AC signals pass through the capacitor from one conductor to the other. Why would you say that it should be inductors being responsible for that when it's clearly happening because I placed the capacitor is there? I haven't placed inductors anywhere.

Comment: You're not thinking that while the capacitor is charging up and storing charge it is stopping the signal do you? It's not like how if the post office is storing incoming letters, then there are no outgoing letters and therefore there is no messages passing through the post office.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing that if a capacitor is charging up, current *must* be flowing through it and therefore a signal is passing through the capcaitor? (such as when non-DC is applied to the the capacitor) Whereas if a capacitor is not charging up then there *must* be no current flowing through it which means there is no signal passing through the capacitor (such as when a capacitor has finished charging up to a constant DC voltage applied to it).

Comment: i was exactly thinking this "You're not thinking that while the capacitor is charging up and storing charge it is stopping the signal do you" oh man I was very confused i thought that when two traces are near to each other and are placed a space apart due to changing AC signal magnetic field will link to another trace and will induce current in opposite direction (Lenz's law) and because of that cross-talk happens only due to inductive action.

Comment: @Ahsan Okay, that explains things on my end.

Comment: if there was capacitive action then like a capacitor holds the charge between two plates the traces near to each other should hold the charges and stop the signal from flowing among them. so it means that when traces are near due to faradays law and Lenz's law cross talk will happen but also due to being very close the electric field of charges in one trace will affect the charges flowing into another trace (by repelling )and this also induces current and it is cross talk due to parasitic capacitance. did I assess right this time?

Comment: add your first comment in the answer and your answer is accepted then

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: exactly. The parasitic actions of storing elements in the transmission lines or in the IC design are very tricky. Discrete components compared to parasitics are simple to understand because a person knows where the component should go to perform the storing action but parasitic becomes sometimes difficult to make sense of how they are affecting the signals.

Comment: @Ahsan Induction is a separate method in which signals can cross an airgap. A capacitor is like a spring, membrane or wall. It is passive and can't oppose anything without energy. When you apply a force to it, it gradually stores enough energy to counterattack that force. For any level of stored energy, it is only enough to oppose one specific level of force. If you increase/decrease the force applied it can't oppose it and instead stores/releases energy until it has the correct potential energy to oppose it. But if you keep changing the force applied it can never block it.

Comment: That's why something like a wall or membrane can block a continuous flow but can't block sound.

Comment: yes makes sense. Thanks a lot for the helpful tips

Answer (score 0):

In comments you said,

> well actually I am thinking parasitic capacitance in transmission lines works as a normal capacitor (I am taking literal meaning ) but the think that has confused me a lot is that normal capacitor stores charge in the form of electrical field lines but in transmission lines we have magnetic field lines because of changing signals so when these magnetic field lines link to the other trace they induce current but this is an inductor phenomena so as the name suggest parasitic capacitance it should store charge right so how it is storing charge and if not then why that so so

Transmission lines don't work soley with the magnetic field. The electric field is also involved, and also stores (momentarily) energy as that energy propagates along the line.

In fact, one way to think about the operation of a transmission line is that the transmission line is a guiding structure for an electromagnetic wave propagating along the line. In this view the currents and voltages on the conductive elements of the line are of secondary importance, and the electric and magnetic fields between the conductors are of primary importance. And, as you probably know, neither an electric nor a magnetic field propagates on its own, both are needed to form an electromagnetic wave.

In another comment you said,

> because dielectric polarization just can't keep up with the fast switching of signal

First, for many dielectrics and signals below the terahertz range, this isn't true. The polarization has no trouble keeping up at RF frequencies.

Second, even if the dielectric polarization can't keep up, what you're left with is a dielectric that acts more like vacuum. And there's no problem in principle with operating a transmission line with vacuum as the dielectric (the difficulty is purely mechanical, as vacuum isn't much use for maintaining the separation between your conductors).

What you do have to worry about is that at high frequencies, if the polarization can't "keep up", the polarization vector gets out of phase with the electric field vector, and this has the same effect as if the dielectric were conductive at these frequencies. This causes the line to become lossy. But if you're working below 1 GHz, it's easy to find dielectrics where this effect is negligible. Even up to 40 or 50 GHz it's not difficult to find good dielectrics, but they become more costly.

Comment: " The electric field is also involved, and also stores (momentarily) energy as that energy propagates along the line " then the electric field lines will cause delay to the propagating signal and is this delaying due to electric field lines are parasitic capacitive issue?

Comment: @Ahsan, the wave propagates according to the electromagnetic wave equation (which can be derived from Maxwell's equations). Is it "because" of the electric field or the magnetic field? I wouldn't say it's one or the other. I'd say it's just the way electomagnetic waves behave.

Comment: makes sense. thank you